# evaluate $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\sin(x)\ \arctan\left(\exp\{{7\cos\left(\ln(x^2+3)\right)}\}\right)}{\cos(x^4)+2016} dx$

Tags: integration

> $$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\sin(x)\ \arctan\left(e^{7\cos\left(\ln(x^2+3)\right)}\right)}{\cos(x^4)+2016} dx$$

The numerator is a multiplication of two odd functions$=$ odd function let's call in $m(x)$

The denominator is a sum of even function$=$ even function let's call in $n(x)$

So we have $$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{m(x)}{n(x)}=\int_{-1}^{0} \frac{m(x)}{n(x)}+\int_{0}^{1} \frac{m(x)}{n(x)}=-\int_{0}^{1} \frac{m(x)}{n(x)}+\int_{0}^{1} \frac{m(x)}{n(x)}=0$$

Is the last move correct? $\int_{-1}^{0} \frac{m(x)}{n(x)}=-\int_{0}^{1} \frac{m(x)}{n(x)}$?

Comment: The antiderivative of an odd function is an even one, so $F(1)-F(-1)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the numerator is the product of an odd function with an *even* function. The "$x^2$" inside there makes it even.

So the integrand is odd (because the product of an odd function with an even function is odd), and the integral is $0$.

[Side note: you say "multiplication of two odd functions= odd function", but this is false. That's how it works with odd and even *integers*, but not with odd and even *functions*. Consider $x$ and $x^3$, both odd. Is their product odd?]

And yes, your argument is correct. But it is overly complicated. If $m$ is odd and $n$ is even, then $\frac{m}{n}$ is odd. So you may as well be looking at $$\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)\,dx$$ for any odd function $f$.

Comment: Do I need to look inside the $\arctan$ function? isn't $\arctan$ an odd function and all that is inside $e^{7\cos(\ln(x^2+3)}$ is just a number?

Comment: $\arctan(x)$ is an odd function of $x$. But $\arctan(e^{7\cos(\ln(x^2+3)})$ is even because $\arctan(e^{7\cos(\ln((-x)^2+3)})=\arctan(e^{7\cos(\ln(x^2+3)})$; that is according to the definition of an "even function".

Comment: I understood the relation (sum, product, quotient ) of even and odd functions, I can just look at $x^n$ when $n$ is odd or even.
I just left with the $\arctan$, if $e^{7\cos(\ln(x^2+3)}=-5$ do not $arctan(-5)=-arctan(-5)$?

Comment: I think I got it, $\arctan$ is composed with $cos$ so we have a composition of an odd function and even function so it is even?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Use $$I=\int_a^bf(x)\ dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)\ dx$$

and $$I+I=\int_a^b\{f(x)+f(a+b-x)\}\ dx$$

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand.
I know that if $f$ is even so $\int_{a}^{b}f=-\int_{-b}^{a}f$ and $\int_{-a}^{a}f=2\int_{0}^{a}f$

and  if $f$ is odd so $\int_{a}^{b}f=-\int_{-b}^{a}f$ and $$\int_{-a}^{a}f=0$

Comment: @gbox, Is $f$ even or odd here?

Comment: I just wrote what I know about odd/even functions